# Improving transformer voltage regulation / efficiency through construction

Tags: transformer, efficiency

I am wondering what modifications can be done to a transformer during manufacturing to improve its voltage regulation and efficiency?

Comment: Nothing should be undertaken during the manufacturing process because transformers are made to a design specification and that is set in stone before the manufacturing process begins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best that can be done during manufacturing is to build the equipment according to the design.

These characteristics are defined during the design stage.

Voltage regulation depends mainly on the leakage impedance, so reducing the stray field reduces the voltage drop. The main way to reduce the stray field is to use fewer turns or to bring the primary and secondary windings closer together. Of course there is trade-offs, a very low impedance creates problems for protection, as in the definition of the circuit breakers and very close windings can cause electrical discharges between them. (in small transformers, such as less than 45kVA, the resistance can considerably influence, in this case, using larger conductors helps).

As for efficiency, it is necessary to reduce losses. This can be achieved using better materials (like copper instead of aluminum for conductors or more refined silicon-steel for the core) or more material, increasing the amount of silicon steel (which ends up reducing the magnetic flux density) or the amount of conductor (which reduces loss by Joule effect).

Answer (score 1):

Slightly dissenting answer: there are ALWAYS manufacturing process parameters that are not covered in the specification: Detailed metallurgy of the core or the wire, glue chemistry and application methods, geometry and order of windings, winding tension, winding speed, material and process for varnishing, etc.

You can try to analyze this but since it also depends partially on your manufacturing environment and your specific equipment, trial and error is often the best method to characterize that.

In order to figure out what "improves" things, you need to define what counts as an "improvement". Cheaper, faster, less lossy, less-buzzy, secondary requirements etc. and these often require trade offs.

Example: we had customer complaints about some audible noise from Europe. Turns out it was the transformer in the power supply that was buzzing when excited with the 220V switching frequency and duty cycle. We switched to a different vendor and the problem disappeared. Apparently the new vendor had a better varnishing process. The original vendor didn't know how to fix this and lost a sizable business over it. The specification just said "thoroughly varnished". There really isn't any industry standard way to specify this in more detail.